# How Do i create a simple Detour Library

Tags: c++, function-hooking

Quite new to Reverse Engineering and making Detour Functions, Just need some form of clarification here, i am trying to make a Simple x86 Detour library and i have worked on something using some Sources i saw on the Internet.
Now i have a challenge with the simple MessageBox does not trigger errors at the same time , it fails to hook as i get this Execption

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F2B3839 (vcruntime140d.dll) in SHook.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x75C51F70.
```

On this Line

```
memcpy(original, FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);
```

My source code looks like this  :

**SHook.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "hde32.h"

class SHook
{
private :
    LPVOID FunctionAddress;
    DWORD TrampolineLength = 0, OriginalProtection;
    hde32s disam;
    BYTE Jump[5] = { 0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
public:
    BOOL SetHook(LPCSTR dll, LPCSTR name, LPVOID proxy, LPVOID original, PDWORD length);
};
```

Now **SHook.cpp**

```
#include "SHook.h"

BOOL SHook::SetHook(LPCSTR dll, LPCSTR name, LPVOID proxy, LPVOID original, PDWORD length)
{
    LPVOID FunctionAddress;
    DWORD TrampolineLength = 0, OriginalProtection;
    hde32s disam;
    BYTE Jump[5] = { 0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    FunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(dll), name);
    if (!FunctionAddress)
        return FALSE;

    //disassemble length of each instruction, until we have 5 or more bytes worth
    while (TrampolineLength < 5)
    {
        LPVOID InstPointer = (LPVOID)((DWORD)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength);
        TrampolineLength += hde32_disasm(InstPointer, &disam);
    }

    //Build the trampoline buffer
    memcpy(original, FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength); //shoots error here
    *(DWORD*)(Jump + 1) = ((DWORD)FunctionAddress + TrampolineLength) - ((DWORD)original + TrampolineLength + 5);
    memcpy((LPVOID)((DWORD)original + TrampolineLength), Jump, 8);

    //Make sure the function is writable
    if (!VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OriginalProtection))
        return FALSE;

    //Build and atomically write the hook
    *(DWORD*)(Jump + 1) = (DWORD)proxy - (DWORD)FunctionAddress - 5;
    //SafeMemcpyPadded(FunctionAddress, Jump, 5);

    //Restore the original page protection
    VirtualProtect(FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength, OriginalProtection, &OriginalProtection);

    //Clear CPU instruction cache
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), FunctionAddress, TrampolineLength);

    *length = TrampolineLength;
    return TRUE;
}
```

And the implementation is looking like this

**MessageBoxTest.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <string>
#include "SHook.h"

typedef int (WINAPI* TdefOldMessageBoxA)(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
TdefOldMessageBoxA myOldMessageBoxA;

SHook shook;
int WINAPI HookMessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType) 
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hooked", "Hooked", MB_OK);
    return myOldMessageBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

void EstablishHook()
{
        myOldMessageBoxA = (TdefOldMessageBoxA)& MessageBoxA;
        shook.SetHook("user32.dll","MessageBoxA", (LPVOID)&HookMessageBoxA, myOldMessageBoxA,0);
}

int main() 
{
    EstablishHook();
}
```

Please Can someone give a clarification what i did miss pls

I am trying to understand what i missed there? Please i do need some form of help here

Comment: `original` seems to point to `MessageBoxA` so you write to non-writable memory. `VirtualProtect` will fix that (as you use afterwards) but this is a logical flaw in your code.

Comment: @JohannAydinbas Pls very new to things like this , just need a help of some sort with the line i should correct, say a snippet would be fine

Comment: Why do you want to create your own library? Take a look at [Microsoft's Detour](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours) library, it probably does everything you want.